# Android Wear: Only "Simple" watchface is working, all others black

Tags: android, android-layout, wear-os

I am trying to get a littlebit into Android Wear watchfaces. I've run into a problem:
When trying to select a different watchface rather than the default "Simple" called watchface, everything I get is a black screen with my Google Now cards on top of it.
--> I can't see any clock, on it's place it's all dark.

Is that normal or why can't I test even pre shipped watchfaces?

Only this watchface is visible:

[image]

All the others look like this, doesn't matter if pre-installed or installed from play store:

[image]

Same issue with square emulator:

[image]

Comment: I can only confirm that I have the same behavior on my emulator.

Comment: @Raanan I've read about people who develop their watchfaces on an emulator. I guess we've got a problem, if others are able to do so, and we are not?

Comment: Do you have "use host GPU" marked, that could solve the issue. I'm testing now.

Comment: @Raanan Yes I've tried to set up my emulator with "use host GPU" and ended up with the same result.

Comment: Did you try with a square emulator? (with GPU)

Comment: Just tried, same result.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem as well.  I deleted my AVD and recreated it with "Use Host GPU" checked and the watch faces are running OK now.
The same thing is necessary if you want to run activities embedded in a notification.

Comment: I was also able to get watch faces to work by enabling Use Host GPU. I didn't have to delete the AVD, I just edited it. It seems that when you are using a Round device in this mode, the masked corners outside the main circular area "leak" so the display actually looks rectangular.